# Do you know how to remove the Error Name in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to use basically "IF" function to find some values in my excel sheet. For example, see attachment: If(A1="OK";"OK";"NOK")

But i get the error #name as a result. The reason is that some of the cells in the sheet have error #name and I cannot correct these cells with error #name.

Do you know how can i do use my function If? Is there a way to avoid these error #name?

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot showing you have used `FIND()` function. Use `=IF(A1="OK";"OK";"NOT OK")`

Comment: I have the same issue with FIND or IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [IsError function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iserror-function-40a89200-138b-4e60-b254-34aea51b2e6b) or [IfError function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) to return specific values when there is an error.

For example, `=IFS(ISERROR(A1);"";A1="OK";"OK";A1<>"OK";"NOK")`, returns "" if A1 returns an error, returns "OK" if A1 returns "OK" and returns "NOK" if A1 doesn't return "OK"